# accessory view. Checkmark

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessoryview

I have a tableview and each cell has a switch as accessory view. I can iterate through all cells to see which ones have switch on. 
I can easily change the accessory view to be a check mark. 
I need to implement that tapping each cell toggles between checkmark and none.

Then in touchupinside, iterate through all cells to see which ones are checked and which ones are not checked.

I have implemented to check for Switch state

```
var indexPaths = table.IndexPathsForVisibleRows; 
foreach (var indexPath in indexPaths) 
{ 
   var cell = table.CellAt (indexPath); 
   var switchView = cell.AccessoryView as UISwitch; 
   if (switchView.On) 
      {
       /*code to handle switch on*/
      } 

}
```

I dont know how to have similar code to check if accessoryview is Checkmark and if it is set to none

Comment: What is your question?  You've just stated what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses MarkupKit's `LMTableView` class to implement selection management:

http://gkbrown.org/2015/08/10/using-lmtableview-to-implement-radio-button-like-behavior-in-ios-applications/

Essentially, you define a particular section of a table view as being either single-select or multi-select, and the `LMTableView` class manages the selection state for you. You can then query the table view to find out which rows are selected, or you can respond to selection events yourself via table view delegate methods.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but you may be able to use MarkupKit with Xamarin. Does it support other third-party libraries?